# PRAM( parallel) algo for Merge sort

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

I was in the middle of reading Multithreaded merge sort in Introduction to algorithm 3rd edition. However I am confused with the number of processors required for the following Merge-Sort algo:

```
MERGE-SORT(A, p, r)
1 if p < r
2 q = (p+r)/2
3 spawn MERGE-SORT(A, p, q)
4 MERGE-SORT(A, q + 1, r)
5 sync
6 MERGE(A, p, q, r)
```

the MERGE is the standard merge algorithm. Now what is the number of processor required for this algorithm ?? Though i am assuming it should be O(N) but the book is claiming it to be O(log n), why? Note i am not multithreading the MERGE procedure. an explaination with an example will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The O(log n) value is not the number of CPUs "required" to run the algorithm, but the actual "parallelism" achieved by the algorithm. Because MERGE itself is not parallelized, you don't get the full benefit if O(n) processors even if you have them all available.

That is, the single-threaded, serial time complexity for merge sort is O(n log n). You can think of 'n' as the cost of merge and 'log n' as the factor that counts in the recursive invocations of merge sort to get the array to a stage where you can merge it. When you parallelize the recursion, but merge is still serial, you save the O(log n) factor but the O(n) factor stays there. Therefore the parallelism is of the order O(log n) when you have enough processors available, but you can't get to O(n).

In yet other words, even if you have O(n) CPUs available, most of them fall idle very soon and less and less CPUs work when the large MERGEs start to take place.

Comment: I understood the O(log n) is Parallelism. But after describing this algo in the book, it said that this algo would achieve linear speed up and from the definition if this achieve the linear speed up then number of processor is O(log n) as Tp = O(n) so it is work optiaml. Though later the book introduced an algorithm with Tp = O((log n)^3) where parallelism is O(n / (log n)^2). But my question is not about parallelism !

Comment: The O(lg3 n) algorithm is one where MERGE is parallelized also. But you answered the question yourself. Because you can only eliminate the O(log n) factor by parallelism, it is enough to have O(log n) parallel executions = CPUs to get the maximum benefit (without parallel MERGE).

Comment: Umm so with recursion depth we are using only O(log n) number of processor to solve it in Tp = O(n) time. Thus p * Tp = O(n log n). Thank you :)

Comment: I have one more question. What is the difference between  the model in this book and PRAM model ??